# Make multiple API calls after an API call

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux

I'm trying to iterate over a list of URLs that comes from an API call. How can I make this code synchronous?

I already tried to use async/await before the .map() iterations but it always goes over towards the dispatch function.

```
  return dispatch => {
    let query = `?`;
    if (currentPage) query += `page=${currentPage}`;
    if (isAlive) query += `&isAlive=${isAlive}`;
    if (name) query += `&name=${name}`;
    dispatch(fetchCharsStart());
    axios
      .get(`https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters${query}`)
      .then(({ data }) => data)
      .then(characters => {
        //Iterating all characters
        characters.map(char => {
          char.fetchedBooks = [];
          //Iterating books for each character...
          char.books.map(url => {
            axios.get(url).then(({ data }) => {
              console.log("Fetching...");
              char.fetchedBooks.push({
                name: data.name,
                release: data.release
              });
            });
          });
        });
        console.log("Characters: ", characters);
        dispatch(fetchCharsSuccess(characters));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        dispatch(fetchCharsFail(err));
      });
  };
};
```

I expected the log of fetchChars() to be `Fetching...` 15 times and only after that the Characters array, but I'm getting the opposite behavior.

Comment: That's because `axios` is async. if you want to wait for all the requests to returns, you need to wrap them all with Promise that will be resolved only when all the requests will finish. Then you could `await` for it.

Comment: The problem is that I'm making an API call in each iteration and I just want to mutate data in there. How Promise would help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behaviour : you are looping over an asynchronous request, but not resolving all the promises before executing the following code, so you are logging "`Characters..."` before fetching all your data.

You were on the good way when you tried `async/await`.

```
getCharacters = async () => {
    let res = await axios.get(`https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters${query}`);
    ...
    ...
    return characters;
};
```

You have to chain your requests using async/await so all your promises are resolved before you execute the rest of your code.

```
let characters = await getCharacters();

characters.map(char => {
    char.fetchedBooks = [];
    //Iterating books for each character...
    char.books.map(url => {
      let books = await getBooks();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export const fetchChars = (currentPage, isAlive, name) => {
return dispatch => {
let query = `?`;
if (currentPage) query += `page=${currentPage}`;
if (isAlive) query += `&isAlive=${isAlive}`;
if (name) query += `&name=${name}`;
dispatch(fetchCharsStart());
axios
  .get(`https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters${query}`)
  .then(({ data }) => {
    return data;
  })
  .then(async characters => {
    //Iterating all characters
    for (let i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
      characters[i].fetchedBooks = [];
      //Iterating books for each character...
      for (let j = 0; j < characters[i].books.length; j++) {
        await axios.get(characters[i].books[j]).then(({ data }) => {
          console.log("Fetching...");
          characters[i].fetchedBooks.push({
            name: data.name,
            release: data.release
          });
        });
      }
    }

    console.log("Characters: ", characters);
    dispatch(fetchCharsSuccess(characters));
  })
```

I solved by using for loops. The .map() was creating extra functional scopes and there was nothing telling the then function to wait for the requests to finish. Now, because for loops doesn't create functional scopes, the async keyword will be in same scope as the await keyword.